# How to set height of parent, dependent on height of selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a scenario where I want to find all elements with a certain class, and then I want to set the parent div's `padding-bottom` value as the sum of its current padding-bottom value + the height of the original div which matched the selector.

So say I have a structure like this:

```
<div class='A'>
    <div class='B'>
        <div class='C'>
            .........
        </div>
        <div class='D'>
            .........
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='B'>
        <div class='C'>
            .........
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='B'>
        <div class='C'>
            .........
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='B'>
        <div class='D'>
            .........
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find all class **D** objects, and then I want to set the `padding bottom` value of their container class **B**, to the height of the class **D** object in question, plus whatever padding-bottom value that class **B** object currently has ..

1. Note that all class **D** objects have different heights ..
2. Every class **B** objects can only have a max of 1 class **D** object
3. Every class **B** objects can only have a max of 1 class **C** object

What jQuery do I need to do the above ?

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Does point 3 that you make have any bearing on the question, or is it used simpy for the ppurpose of illustration that divs other than the target and the container are not the only entities that exist?

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.D').each(function(){
   $(this).parent().css("paddingBottom", "+=" + $(this).height() +"px");
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Zxav9/14/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('div.D').each(function(index){
      var dHeight = $(this).height();
      var bPadding = $(this).parent().css('padding-bottom');
      var newPadding = parseInt(dHeight) + parseInt(bPadding);
      $(this).parent().css('padding-bottom', String(newPadding) + 'px');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should the solution for the problem that you've described. But I think you've missed some details. (this code might be shortened to a one liner though)

```
$(function() { 'use strict';
    $('.A > .D').each(function() {
        var $D = $(this);
        var $B = $D.closest('.B');

        $B.css('padding-bottom', 
            $D.height() + parseInt($B.css('padding-bottom'))
        );
    });
});
```

In case you want to include the height of the **.C** elements too:

```
$(function() { 'use strict';
    $('.A > .D, .A > .C').each(function() {
        var $X = $(this);
        var $B = $X.closest('.B');

        $B.css('padding-bottom', 
            $X.height() + parseInt($B.css('padding-bottom'))
        );
    });
});
```